# Linear programming with equality constraints

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I want to find a solution to the minimisation problem

$$
\text{min } c^Tx \qquad \text{subject to } Ax=b
$$

I have implemented the [parametric self-dual simplex](https://support.dce.felk.cvut.cz/pub/hanzalek/_private/ref/Vanderbei_Linear_Programming.pdf) by R. Vanderbei in Matlab and it works perfectly with *inequality* constraints (tested it with multiple examples)

It solves a maximisation problem
$$
\text{max } c^Tx \qquad \text{subject to } Ax\leq b
$$

I also want it to work with equality constraints, so I've rewritten the equality constraints as inequality constraints (with slack variables $w$):
$$
Ax + w\leq b \\
-Ax - w \leq -b
$$

(and for the minimisation problem I will need to take $-c^T$). So then the constraints will look like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & I & 0\\
-A & 0 &-I
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
x \\ w \\ w
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
b \\ -b
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is this the correct approach? Either my implementation or the method is wrong, because my algorithm doesn't work for equality constraints.

Comment: Solved; replace $-I$ with $I$ and the second slack variable should be different, e.g. $v$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced $-I$ with $I$ and used a different slack variable $v$, then the algorithm works fine